# Por que a necessidade de utilizar o "result as T" no retorno de um método genérico?

Tags: typescript, angular

Considere o seguinte método:

```
private handleError<T> (operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
        this.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);
        return of(result as T);
    };
}
```

Considerando que a implementação de um tipo genérico implica um retorno do mesmo tipo do genérico `T`, por que a necessidade de utilizar o `result as T`, sendo que `result` será sempre do tipo `T`?

```
return of(result as T);
```

Comment: O que é este `of`?

Comment: @Maniero é um [método](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-of) do `Observable`, que pertence a biblioteca RxJs utilizada no Angular.